# Repeat same method on multiple objects in python

Tags: python, list, pandas

This is very basic but I am having trouble finding an answer through google. I have a loop that imports a number of text files into pandas dataframes.

I have written the names to a list.

```
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) and join(mypath,f).endswith('.txt') ]

dataframelist = []

for filenum in range(1,len(onlyfiles)):
 path = 'path/%s' % onlyfiles[filenum]
 print path
 name = onlyfiles[filenum][:-4]
 dsname = name
 print name
 name = pd.read_csv(path, sep = '\t')
 print '%s has been imported' % dsname
 dataframelist.append(dsname)
```

I am now looking to run the to_sql() method on each object but cannot seem to find the right syntax. The objects are already instantiated, to my understanding but the interpreter thinks I am trying to manipulate string objects.

I then take the list of pandas objects

```
#if a dataframe exists and has a '-customer' at the end then import

custlist = []

for item in list(dataframelist):
  if item.endswith('-customer'):
        custlist.append(item)
```

and try and loop with the method

```
for dsname in range(1,5):
    ds_to_sql = custlist[dsname]
    print ds_to_sql
    (ds_to_sql.to_sql('%s', engine)) % ds_to_sql
```

I am sure this is quite basic and I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: how have you tried to run the `to_sql` method?

Comment: I have added the other code block to the question

Comment: So what is `custlist`? What does it contain? What is `ds_to_sql` each time - a string, or a dataframe object?

Comment: Can you show us the error that python is telling you? The to_sql method is for inserting data into a *table* in a DB for which you already have a connection established. Are you sure you have a connection? What is the value of the engine variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
 name = onlyfiles[filenum][:-4] #name = 'example.txt'
 dsname = name #dsname = name = 'example.txt'
 print name
 name = pd.read_csv(path, sep = '\t') #name = DataFrame
 print '%s has been imported' % dsname
 dataframelist.append(dsname) #'example.txt' is appended
```

I've added comments with what's happenning at each stage. While you are loading your dataframes - you never save them! You only keep their names in the list.